# Unable to populate input fields inside the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

I am unable to populate the input fields inside the form.
What is the reason for this? I spent so much time looking for the right answer on internet but unfortunately nothing yet.

To better understand my problem I will provide the link to the website: http://flyingcowproduction.com/pls/ and click on the registration button.

I am pretty sure CSS is not an issue but jquery. I am not sure how to approach to the problem in order to solve it.

Many many many thanks in advance for helping me figuring this problem out. It's been bugging me for days now.

Best regards,

-Davorin

Comment: It might help if you post the code you're using to populate the said form.

Comment: `$('form input[type="text"]').val('SET ME')`

Comment: do you mean the reservations button?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it appears that one of your plugins is hijacking keyboard input and preventing the form from getting focus and input

Comment: Also the div with id `loading` is going absolutely nuts - constantly changing the background position.

Comment: @Ariel, what do you mean its changing the background position? It works fine on all major browsers. The website scrolls from left to right to browse. Not sure what kind of experience you have on your side. Please let me know so I can fix the problem. Many thanks!!!

Comment: @SeanThompson, thanks I will look into that. I do have a script that controls site's navigation though.

Comment: just found out that keyboard is fine by using tabs I was able to populate the form but the mouse doesn't. How weird is this?!

Comment: @DavorinSavovic You can also right click on an input. One of your plugins is intercepting your mouse clicks.

Comment: @DavorinSavovic There is no visible change on the website, but my dom inspector is showing constant (pointless) activity which is slowing down the page. You have some sort of timer (`setInterval` or `setTimeout`) that is running far too often. The page is loaded - that div should not be doing anything anymore, you probably hid the div but forgot to stop the timer.

Comment: @DavorinSavovic, can't see anything with that timer firing every millisecond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem appears to be in your `desktop.js` file, which contains the functions mousedownhandler and mouseuphandler, both of which used `e.preventDefault()` to of course, prevent the default behavior of the mouse.  These functions are applied to event listeners attached to  the `div` with the id `singleContentContainer`, which contains everything, including your form.

I am fairly certain that if you comment out the following two lines:

line 194:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

and 238:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

You will be able to select form elements again.  If that doesn't work, I'll continue debugging after you have done so.

**Edit**

As to why your form is not submitting, it appears to be the cause of an option in your `jquery.mobile-1.0a2.js` script; you have 'use ajax forms where possible' enabled; on line `3094`, of that file, is `event.preventDefault();`, this occurs if that option is enabled, and since it is.. well, you can guess the rest.

The option is configured on line `2934`.

As to why the submission isn't working, your relative url is coming up as a [`404 not found error`, indicating it doesn't exist](http://flyingcowproduction.com/process.php).  Your form submits fine, it just isn't getting processed because the process file doesn't exist in the relative path you used to point to it.

Comment: You are my hero my friend as well as the rest of you guys. You are awesome. I have been trying to figure out this problem for few days now! Thank you so so so much!!! Best regards to all of you fellas :D

Comment: It's embarrassing but, now only one more thing is left before all the functionalities of this website are functional and that is the processing button. It won't work. I just was able to realize that now. :/

Comment: @DavorinSavovic Looking into it.

Comment: @DavorinSavovic I've updated my answer.  If you like this answer, and feel it solves your problem, please click the green checkmark under the vote-down button, to accept the answer.

Comment: You saved me!!! Thanks a million; no billion!!! I am definitely giving you all stars for this :) I wish there is more I could do. I truly appreciate the help!

Comment: I am trying to vote but I don't see anywhere the option how?! :/

Comment: @DavorinSavovic It's a clear/outline of a check mark.  Let me see if I can find you a picture.

Comment: @DavorinSavovic See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf74q.png).  That outlined checkmark is what you want to click.

Comment: OMG the UI is terrible. I would never guess it was the rating button. The outline is even hard to spot in the first place. Anyways, thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @DavorinSavovic You're welcome; I'm glad I was able to assist.